# How to directly render Compositing ONLY - without 3D scene?

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes

[image: render composited preloaded external image sequence without 3D scene]

Does anybody have a solution in form of script, some addon or some 'hack' how to render only composited image sequences and passes that you have loaded in Compositing Nodes?

Blender doesn't do that **directly** because blender **firstly render 3D scene** (even 3d scene is empty) and then shortly produce render image for current frame from Compositing Nodes...

As you know blender Compositing can be awesome, I want use it like Nuke, but this is barrier for fast using in sense of speed-up post-processing.

Comment: If you mean directly render only images (from **Image** node) that you process using Compositing nodes (and the whole scene isn't important for you), then the solution might be deleting **Render Layers** node and plugging only **Image** node with the desired image.

Comment: That's strange, if there are no renderlayer nodes in your compositing setup, blender shouldn't be rendering the scene. Is it possible you could upload your .blend?

Comment: Just add a composite node. Try making a new file and copying your stuff over to it with append then, re-render.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it does really *render* the empty scene (maybe add some meshes and lights to test this)?

If you only have file output nodes and no composite output blender will show an empty render image when finished with the compositing since it got nothing to show from your node pipeline. So just add a composite node as output to your node setup like John Roper said ...

Comment: If you are right, it would give us composited images to output directory much more faster ! Yes I am 100% sure blender first look 3d scene and then calculate composite image because you cannot disable every render layer, at least one render layer must be enabled....
[link](http://i.imgur.com/GqeWvcf.jpg)[link]

View image on this link...

Comment: Dont mix up render layers with render layer input node ... Yes one render layer had to be enabled but in your composite nodes should be no render layer input node.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you scene has a camera in it. You don't need anything else, but you MUST have a camera. Then either do a regular render and just immediately cancel it, or do an OpenGL render (both available via the main Render Menu, or various buttons at the bottom of the UI.) Then unplug and replug your image into the Composite node.

Comment: Listen, I dont need blender to render scene ! I want to immediately have rendered image from composite! Rendering of empty scene is too longer than second phase: outputing composited image for current frame ! Just look at the image I posted up there...

Comment: It should be possible to write a script or addon for this, but it doesn't seem to exist yet (at least I couldn't find one quickly on google). At the moment, you need to have initialized a render. This takes like half a second, so I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: @Drudge Half a second per frame adds up when rendering animations

Comment: @gandalf3 It's not half a second per frame. It's half a second per session when opening your file and wanting to get the compositor to show an image loaded from a file.

Comment: @Drudge In that case, all you should need to do is change frame or ctrl+shift click on the last node. Not sure why this isn't working in the OP's case?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. I'm pretty sure that you would be having a separate Compositing editor open which might have two separate nodes of Render Layers and Composite.

In my case, there was this Compositing editor already open by default in the Compositing tab on the top. And on top of that, I opened another compositing editor by sliding one window to right. That way, what I was getting is my scene render then my texture render.